# How to get folders by Name?

Tags: google-docs-api

Apologies if this has already been addressed at https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/google-documents-list-api#!forum/google-documents-list-api, but I'm not seeing the search facility there, perhaps because the forum's been closed.

I'm probably missing something, but based on https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_list_of_documents_and_files don't seem to be able to combine ?title=blah or ?q=blah with any of the following and get the expected results:
- ?showfolders=true
- /contents/-/folder
- /-/folder

Alternative approach is to get all files & folders with ?showfolders=true and then identify which are folders:
- is there an element in that identifies a resource as a folder rather than a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a resource is a folder by checking if it has a category with `scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"` and `term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder"`:

For example:

```
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
  term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder"/>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that did the job.  
P.S. Is there a way to use the ?title=blah or ?q=blah approach with folders?

Answer (score 0):

You might also check out Cloudward's approach to publishing Google Docs by ID and Name. Here are two Cloud Snippets you can use:

Publish Google Doc by Name:
https://snippets.cloudward.com/app_listing.espx?template_id=1bbba611a85b3b6b4a3ea274f9ad3796&account_id=

Publish Google Doc by ID:
https://snippets.cloudward.com/app_listing.espx?template_id=51925e7ed2166d7d83a8c32fa1ee88dd&account_id=